# Why am I getting a 404 server error htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess

Im trying to add a simple rewrite rule so that any request sent to /api/v1/ will be processed by /api/v1/api.php

Currently it does a 404 on my when I try and run the example method /api/v1/example

Im following this [tutorial](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php) but little confused where to put my rewrite rule in my current htaccess file.

What I have so far in my htaccess file is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L] # 404 
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Ive tried the wordpress method but that doesn't work either

```
 add_rewrite_rule('^api/v1/(.*)$','api/v1/api.php?request=$1','top');
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing similar - so in my `/path/to/doc/root/api/v1/.htaccess` I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /api/v1/index.php [L]
```

This ONLY catches requests in the `/api/v1/` directory or lower, so the rest of my stuff still generates normal 404 errors, etc.

Comment: nah that just ends up giving me a forbidden error :/

Comment: @MrJoshFisher - works on my system, i've enabled `mod_rewrite` globally. Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04 server...

Comment: I believe I'm running the same the main mod_rewrite in my root directory are working but the htaccess in /api/v1/ is causing a forbidden error :/

Comment: @MrJoshFisher something in your main htaccess causing a conflict? what is showing for the error in the server logs?

Comment: Currently its "GET /api/v1/ HTTP/1.0" 403 874" - https://api.fisherinc.co.uk/api/v1/ if I put an index.php file in that sorts it but just gives a white screen and doesn't redirect to the api.php file :/